# Cypress - Returning an array that contains an object and an index

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm trying to write a command in Cypress that finds an element in set of pages and returns an array that contains the element on [0] and the index of the page on [1].
I tried using `console.log(elmFound)` to see the found element and it's working fine. The only issue is that the Cypress can't use the `elmFound[0]` as I expect it to (for example - search an element inside of it).

This is the command itself:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('findTempOrProgByName', (navigatorObj, objElmCss, objElmTitleCss, objName)=>{
    var elm = [];
    cy.get(navigatorObj)        //Searching in each page
        .each(($el, index, $list)=>{
            if((index != 0) && (index != $list.length-1))
            {
                cy.wrap($el).click();
                cy.wait(1000);

                cy.get(objElmCss)    //Searching each element in the page
                    .each(($ProgFound)=>{
                        cy.wrap($ProgFound)
                            .find(objElmTitleCss)
                            .invoke('text')
                            .then((text)=>{
                                if(text.match(objName)) //If the title matches, push it to the array
                                {
                                    elm.push($ProgFound.get(0));
                                    elm.push(index);
                                    // return false;
                                }
                            })
                        })
            }
        }).then(()=>{
            console.log('This is from the command. This is the elm object:', elm);
            return elm;
        })
})
```

This is the usage of it:

```
When('user searches for a specific element', ()=>{
        cy.findTempOrProgByName(progObjects.pagesNavigationUL, 
                                progObjects.programsObjs, 
                                progObjects.programsTitle, 
                                'בוטנים אדם המלך')
        .then((elmFound)=>{
            console.log('From Feature. This is the Array:', elmFound);
            console.log('From Feature. This is the Element:', elmFound[0]);
            console.log('From Feature. This is the index:' + elmFound[1]);
            cy.get(cy.wrap(elmFound[0]).find(progObjects.programsTitle))
                .invoke('text')
                .should('include.text', 'בוטנים אדם המלך');     
//I'm counting on that the element is in the last page, but the index is used to go back to the page where I found the element.
        });
    })
```

For an example, this is the element I was searching for:

[image]

Each page contains max of 10 elements like this.

When I tried running it, it printed to the console the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3eQ7.png)

It finds the right element but then it searches for `{specwindow: \<window\>, chainerid: ch-https://app.staging.aimpact.ai-344}` as an element instead of the actual element:

[image]

This is the error that appears:

[image]

Any of you has an idea of how to get that returned element correctly and use it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 3):

It should work if `cy.findTempOrProgByName()` remains on the same page as the element as per this comment: `//I'm counting on that the element is in the last page`.

If not, the element reference you get is now stale, because the `.each(($el, index, $list) //Searching in each page` will carry on passed the page with your found element.

A better approach would be to take references to page and element in aliases. When you use the alias value later in the test, Cypress re-queries the DOM to make sure the values are fresh.

**Searching**

```js
cy.get(navigatorObj)        // Searching in each page
  .each(($page, pageIndex, $list) => {
    if((pageIndex !== 0) && (pageIndex !== $list.length-1)) {
      cy.wrap($page).click();
      //cy.wait(1000);

      cy.get(objElmCss)                // Searching each element in the page   
        .should('have.length.gt', 0)   // instead of cy.wait() above
        .each(($progFound) => {
          if($progFound.find(objElmTitleCss).text().match(objName)) {
            // If the title matches, set alias
            cy.wrap($progFound).as('progFound')
            cy.get(navigatorObj).eq(pageIndex).as('pageFound') 
          }
        })
    }
  })
```

**Accessing**

```js
cy.get('@pageFound').click()  // go back to page where found

cy.get('@progFound')
  .find(progObjects.programsTitle)
  .invoke('text')
  .should('include.text', 'בוטנים אדם המלך')
```

There may be some other optimizations needed, I can't really tell without running an actual test, but `alias` is definitely the way to go especially since Cypress v12 upgraded the mechanism to automatically re-query the DOM for changes.